# SELECT with WHERE NOT IN condition without subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I wonder if this is possible to have the same results as the following request without using a subquery:

```
SELECT p1.id
FROM products p1
WHERE NOT p1.id IN (
  SELECT p2.id
  FROM products p2
  JOIN product_translations t
    ON t.product_id = p2.id
   AND t.locale = 'fr'
);
```

As you can see, a `products` row can have many `product_translations` rows (0..n).

The expected result must be only products that does not have `product_translations` with locale `fr`.

Comment: Why do you want to do it without a subquery (although a NOT EXISTS might be faster than a NOT IN)

Comment: SELECT p2.id
  FROM products p2
  LEFT JOIN product_translations t
   ON t.heroshop_record_id = p2.id
   AND t.locale = 'fr'
   WHERE t.heroshop_record_id is null

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name exactly or may be a left join to product_translations and by using IS NULL condition on a column on the `product_translations` table.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I've edited the query

Comment: @mhn your solution seems to work, do you know which one is the most efficient ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The join inside the sub-query is not needed. Your query thus equals:

```
SELECT id
FROM products
WHERE id NOT IN 
(
  SELECT product_id 
  FROM product_translations
  WHERE locale = 'fr'
);
```

Without a sub-query you would have to outer join the translation table and eliminate the matches:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_translations pt ON pt.product_id = p.id AND pt.locale = 'fr'
WHERE pt.product_id IS NULL;
```

Edit: Just for completeness' sake here is the NOT EXISTS version (also needing a sub-query of course):

```
SELECT id
FROM products
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM product_translations
  WHERE product_id  = products.id
  AND locale = 'fr'
);
```

Comment: I did not think about that way, thank you! Do you know which one will be the most efficient ?

Comment: A great dbms would recognize that NOT IN, NOT EXISTS and the LEFT JOIN technique actually do the same thing here and would internally always use the same execution plan. MySQL is not that great. It is known for being fast on joins and slow on IN clauses. But still, depending on the number of records in the tables, the number of matches and appropriate indexes existing or not, it can be different here. Just try. You can also use EXPLAIN to see the execution plans.

Comment: Recent versions of MySQL do optimize such queries ([according to the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html), at least)

Comment: @RandomSeed: I don't use MySQL myself, so I mainly repeated here what I read and heard about it. It's good to know that MySQL has obviously worked on these performance issues. Thanks for the information and the link.